# Why some developers use 'return' in setState Updater and others don't?

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering what happens if we omit the 'return' keyword in the setState() updater function ? Is there even a difference ?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're talking about? The setState function accepts an object and a callback function

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm talking about the FUNCTIONAL setState()

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Never mind. I know the answer : Arrow functions have implicit returns. But if the return type is an object we have two choices : either use `return {.....}` or `=> ({...})` (notice the parentheses!)